# Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String? Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, mapbox

I am receiving this error message "Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?'" associated with this line "point.title = r" and this line "point.subtitle = z". I've tried lots of things like place.description which makes the entire array a string...

```
//I have multiple arrays, lat, long and pass besides place.
var place = [String]()

//I have four of the chunks of code for each array
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jSONData, options: .AllowFragments)
            if let dataFile3 = json["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for c in dataFile3 {
                    if let placeName = c["PlaceName"] {
                        place.append((placeName as? String)!)

for var (i,x) in zip(lat, long) {
            for _ in place {
                for _ in pass {
            print(i)
            print(x)
            //print(i + ", " + x)

        // String to double conversion, can I do this when I set the array as a string?
        let lati = NSString(string: i).doubleValue
        let longi = NSString(string: x).doubleValue


        //I have a list of values array so I need to have a for loop that inputs the value over and over again.
        var point = MGLPointAnnotation()
            point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lati, longitude: longi)

            point.title = place
            point.subtitle = pass

        mapView.addAnnotation(point)
            }}}

        //var i and x for loop
        }

    //viewDidLoad
    }

    //creates the markers popup for each point with data
    func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        // Always try to show a callout when an annotation is tapped.
        return true
    }
```

How do I fix the error above?

EDIT:
With Santosh's help this is what I changed...

```
let point = MGLPointAnnotation()

        var i = lat
        var x = long

        //lat and long is served and then all the r,z points, then another lat, long...need to fix this and it may work.
        for (i,x) in zip(lat, long) {
            for aPlace in place {
                for aPass in pass {
            print(i)
            print(x)

        // String to double conversion, can I do this when I set the array as a string?
        let lati = NSString(string: i).doubleValue
        let longi = NSString(string: x).doubleValue

        point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lati, longitude: longi)


            point.title = aPlace
            print(aPlace)


            point.subtitle = aPass
            print(aPass)

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(point)
            }}}
```

This is running correctly now or at least reporting the correct values but the loop just keeps a loopin...

Comment: `place` is an `array` so you need to access the item from within that array. Because `point.title` accepts an `optional String` which is `String?`. And that's what the error says.

Comment: yes that is basically what I was thinking, just don't know how to fix it...I'm using your suggestions below but I don't think it made any difference unfortunately. I do appreciate your efforts.

Comment: What error did you get in below answer?

Comment: added a new chunk above for you to see. need to stop the loop after 105 records.

Comment: I see 3 loops so check which loop is having more values and restrict it to whatever value you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//I have four of the chunks of code for each array
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jSONData, options: .AllowFragments)
    if let dataFile3 = json["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        for c in dataFile3 {
            if let placeName = c["PlaceName"] {
                place.append((placeName as? String)!)

                for var (i,x) in zip(lat, long) {
                    for aPlace in place {
                        for aPass in pass {
                            print(i)
                            print(x)
                            //print(i + ", " + x)

                            // String to double conversion, can I do this when I set the array as a string?
                            let lati = NSString(string: i).doubleValue
                            let longi = NSString(string: x).doubleValue


                            //I have a list of values array so I need to have a for loop that inputs the value over and over again.
                            var point = MGLPointAnnotation()
                            point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lati, longitude: longi)

                            point.title = aPlace
                            point.subtitle = aPass

                            mapView.addAnnotation(point)
                        }}}

                //var i and x for loop
            }

            //viewDidLoad
        }
}
```